# ASP.NET MVC2 instant 404 Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.net MVC2 website that was working great when using Visual Studio 2010 RC
But after installing Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, i have been seeing nothing but 404 errors from my mvc website.

I'm pretty sure it actually is a MVC2 app, but after reading around i'm getting confused.
But how that could result in the 404 errors im getting now, i dont know.

The problem occurs when trying to debug the website from visual studio.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the 404 errors by removing the System.Web.MVC Reference and then adding it...